# How add text in D3 mouseover?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a heatmap chart in D3 and I can't figure out how to add the text on mouseover. I am not sure how to proceed. If you could give me some clues, I would appreciate it. In the following snippet you can find the code. both the working and the non-working codeblocks. Thanks!

````
console.log(d3)

let screenWidth = 800
let screenHeight = 400

//load data
d3.csv('./datos/locations.csv').then(function(data){
    let filtered = []
    for(let item of data) {
        if(item.location === "location one") {
            filtered.push(item)
        }
    }

    build(filtered)
})

//Create canvas
function createSVG() {
    let container = d3.select('#container')
    svg = container.append('svg')
    .attr('id', 'canvas')
    .attr('width', screenWidth)
    .attr('height', screenHeight)
}

//Create chart
function build(data) {

    let rectWidth = screenWidth / 24
    let rectHeight = screenHeight / 7

    let rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
        .attr('x', function(d,i) {
            return (parseInt(d.hour) - 1) * rectWidth})
        .attr('y', function(d,i){
            return (parseInt(d.day) - 1) * rectHeight})  
        .attr('height', rectHeight) 
        .attr('width', rectWidth)
        .style('fill', 'black')
        .style('stroke', 'white')
        .on('mouseover', function(d,i) {
            let rects = d3.select(this)
            .append('text')
            .attr('x')
            .attr('y')
            .style('font-weight', 500)
            .style('font-family', 'Arial')
            .style('fill', 'red')
            .text(function (d,i) {return d.value})})
        }

function main() {
    createSVG()
    build()
}

main()
```
````

Comment: d3 is a framework that relies heavily on debugging. For future questions, please turn your code into a [mre], it will help you get better answers. See also [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append a `<div>` with `position: absolute` to body and position it on mousemove event. Change the opacity to update its display or hidden.

```
var div = d3.select('body').append('div')   
    .attr('class', 'tooltip')               
    .style('opacity', 0);

...
.on('mouseover', function(d) {      
    div.transition()        
        .duration(200)      
        .style('opacity', .9);      
    div.html('<h3>' + d.status + '</h3>' + '<p>' + timeFormat(new Date(d.date)) + ' at ' + monthDayFormat(new Date(d.date)) + '</p>')  
        .style('left', (d3.event.pageX) + 'px')     
        .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 28) + 'px');    
    })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z9ucLqu2/

Answer (score 0):

`<text>` nodes cannot be children of `<rect>`s, only just as `<line>`s or `<circle>`s can't. They are figure nodes and are not meant to have children. Append the tooltip to the SVG or a `<g>` instead.

This means that you cannot access `d.value` through the `function (d,i) {return d.value})` anymore, but you *can* get it because you have access to `d` from `.on('mouseover', function(d,i) {`, just remove everything but `d.value`.

If you use `x` and `y` from the `<rect>`, what is going to happen is that the `<text>` element covers the `<rect>`, catches the mouse event and triggers a `mouseout` immediately on the `<rect>`. Since you'll probably want to remove the tooltip on `mouseout`, you'll get the text node flickering on and off. Either move the text to the right by at least `rectWidth` or use `d3.event` to get the mouse coordinates of the event and position it a little down and to the right, using something like `.attr('x', d3.event.clientX + 10)` to move it right.